# lxml cleaner to ignore base64 image

Tags: python, security, lxml

I use lxml.html.clean to remove untrusted input in my html code. I realised that lxml removes the `data:` tag in my code. However I want to insert an image in base64 format (from a database, I have no file) so I need this tag. For instance take

```
from lxml.html.clean import Cleaner
cleaner = Cleaner()
cleaner.clean_html("""
    <img src="http://test.com/img.png"/>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,aGVsbG8="/>
""")
```

The result is `'<span><img src="http://test.com/img.png"><img src=""></span>'`. The first image is not escaped, the second yes.

Any idea how I could make it accept my base64 code without letting pass vulnerabilities ?

Comment: Can the cleaner process an already parsed DOM? You could do this by whitelisting in that you'd walk the DOM, store the `data:` URIs you want to keep in a custom attribute, say `data-src`. The cleaner should hopefully ignore these attributes when you run it against the DOM, afterwards you walk it again and restore the URIs back into `src`.

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you propose. First clean the text and then insert the image ? Unfortunately I can't, it's a method called just before the rendering of a template and I can not change the workflow.

Comment: Hm. A yet more hackish workaround would be using a bit of Javascript to restore the `src` attributes when the page is loaded, but I admit that's already pretty ugly. Also, the cleaner is [written in Python](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/master/src/lxml/html/clean.py) - you could use a Python debugger to poke around it to see why it removes `data:` URIs and whether one of the documented options affects that behaviour.

Comment: I think the best solution would be to tell LXML to exclude the pattern image base64. But how is the question :)

Comment: That's what I'm getting at. Stepping through the LXML implementation would tell you why it's *included*.

Comment: I think the reason to exclude base64 is because it can easily contain obfuscated javascript code (which is something you want to avoid). eg: data:text/html;base64,PGh0bWw+PHNjcmlwdCB0eXBlPSJ0ZXh0L2phdmFzY3JpcHQiPmFsZXJ0KCdoaScpPC9zY3JpcHQ+PC9odG1sPg== contains javascipt. I think I will try to find a workaround to avoid using base64 and potentially creating vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this behavioral after installing lxml 3.1.0.
Here is solution based on "monkey patching" - replacing lookup regex pattern in `lxml.html.clean` module to exclude links that has data:image/.*;base64 from removal.

```
import re
import lxml
from lxml.html.clean import Cleaner
new_pattern = '\s*(?:javascript:|jscript:|livescript:|vbscript:|data:[^(?:image/.+;base64)]+|about:|mocha:)'

print(new_pattern)

lxml.html.clean._javascript_scheme_re = re.compile(new_pattern, re.I)


cleaner = Cleaner()
dochtml = """
    <img src="http://test.com/img.png"/>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,aGVsbG8="/>
    <img src="data:unsafe/contents;base64,aGVsbG8="/>
    <img src="data:text/html;base64,PGh0bWw+PHNjcmlwdCB0eXBlPSJ0ZXh0L2phdmFzY3JpcHQiPmFsZXJ0KC‌​doaScpPC9zY3JpcHQ+PC9odG1sPg=="/>
"""
r = cleaner.clean_html(dochtml)
print(r)
```

Result

```
<span><img src="http://test.com/img.png">
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,aGVsbG8=">
    <img src="">
    <img src="">
</span>
```

The downside of it - it relies on internal variable name which is not announced in public interface for Cleaner. So module developers could change the name of variable or improve their version of regex.

To be one the safe side and I would create URL handler on web server to return image contents out of database by id. So in your html doc it would be something like this `<img src="http://myserver/showimg?id=123213">`. But this would involve adding lots of additional moving parts - like having web server etc. Also it won't work if it is undesirable for whole world to be have access to those images.

***Old answer:***

It should be possible to configure Cleaner to keep these tags, but I cannot reproduce your case - it just works for me. I'm using python 2.7.2 and lxml 2.2.8 win-32.
Please clarify what python and lxml version do you have?

I tried to run your example and got back second image tag contents that were not removed

Comment: Thanks. I just tested on both python 2.7.3 and python 3.3.0, both lxml 3.1.0 on linux, I have the behaviour. Maybe it's related to the lxml version.

Comment: Indeed, bug fix with 2.3.1 "HTML cleaning didn't remove 'data:' links." http://lxml.de/2.3/changes-2.3.1.html

Comment: Thank you for information. I'll install newer version of lxml and will play with it tomorrow